# MSBuild - Just copy the files in TeamCity

Tags: msbuild, teamcity

I have folders and files in a Team Foundation Server project which when altered and checked in, need to get deployed to a folder on the build server. There is no solution or project files.

I'm not that familiar with MSBuild, so I took a working build.xml for a VS2012 project in TeamCity, edited it so that it would copy over the files, but nothing happens after TeamCitygets the latest sources.

What am I doing wrong in the build.xml?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
 <Project DefaultTargets="Copy" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
   <Target Name="Copy">
      <Copy SourceFiles="@(PackagedFiles)" 
            DestinationFiles="@(PackagedFiles->'\\SomeFolder\CredentialOnline\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)')"/>
 </Target> 
</Project>
```

Comment: What's the content of @(PackagedFiles)? You can use the Message task to display it, like `<Message Text="Files: @(PackagedFiles)"/>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Project DefaultTargets="CopyToDeployFolder" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Target Name="CopyToDeployFolder">
    <Exec Command="echo D| xcopy.exe  $(teamcity_build_checkoutDir) c:\Someplace /s /Y"  />

  </Target>
 </Project>
```

Answer (score 0):

The below will let you "fine tune" the files you want.
If you don't want to exclude anything, just remove the "Exclude=" clause.

FYI : WorkingDir is a custom variable, that is my "root directory".

```
<ItemGroup>
    <MyExcludeFiles Include="$(WorkingDir)\**\SuperSecretStuff.txt" />
    <MyExcludeFiles Include="$(WorkingDir)\**\SuperSecretStuff.doc" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <MyIncludeFiles Include="$(WorkingDir)\**\*.*" Exclude="@(MyExcludeFiles)"/>
</ItemGroup>        



<Copy
SourceFiles="@(MyIncludeFiles)"
DestinationFiles="@(MyIncludeFiles->'$(OutputDir)\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)')"
/>
```

You may not have anything in your "PackagedFiles".
Here is a way to list them out.

```
<Message Text="List of files using special characters (carriage return)"/>
<Message Text="@(PackagedFiles->'&quot;%(fullpath)&quot;' , '%0D%0A')"/>
<Message Text="   "/>
<Message Text="   "/>
```